# Why we cannot solve $y^{2}+\sin y =2 x^{3}+C$ for y?

Tags: elementary-functions

This is from *Stewart - Calculus - Early Transcedentals*

> Writing the equation in differential form and integrating
> both sides, we have $$ \begin{aligned} (2 y+\cos y) d y &=6 x^{2} d x
> \\ \int(2 y+\cos y) d y &=\int 6 x^{2} d x \\ y^{2}+\sin y &=2 x^{3}+C
>  \end{aligned} $$  where $C$ is a constant. This equation gives the
> general solution implicitly. In this case it's impossible to solve the
> equation to express $y$ explicitly as a function of $x$.

I would like to hear a very technical answer on **why it is impossible to solve the equation to express *y* explicity as a function of *x***. Right now I know that I do not know how to solve it for $y$. How can I logically conclude that, it is in fact impossible to solve and not me who ignores some special technique.

Comment: What is your definition of "express $y$ explicitely as a function of $x$"? Which functions do we allow?

Comment: @SeverinSchraven Expressing $y$ in terms of $x$, $y=f(x)$

Comment: Recall that $x=\cos(x)$ does not show an analytical solution. This is the problem of *transcendental* equations.

Comment: Note that $y^2+\sin(y)\geq -1$, however, $x^3+C$ can get arbitrary negative. So we would need to specify a domain, where we can solve the equation.

Comment: Showing there's no elementary solution of $y^2+\sin y=a$ for $y$ in terms of $a$ is a lot longer and more advanced than anything commonly done in introductory Calculus.